# Trouble to set HTTPS on ASP.NET Core 2.1 + IIS

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, https, asp.net-core-2.1, iis-8.5

I am trying to configure https to my website hosted on IIS on a Windows Server 2012. My project is a default WebApi application from ASP.NET Core 2.1 and I am using [win-acme](https://github.com/PKISharp/win-acme/releases) to configure IIS with a Let’s Encrypt certificate.

Everything runs fine besides the fact that http traffic is not being redirected to https. If I check the logs, I get:

> ```
> warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
>       Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
> ```

I thought that this could be easily solved by adding this to my `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.RedirectStatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
    options.HttpsPort = 443;
});
```

However, now I can’t access my website at all. Chrome gives me a message:

> This page isn't working www.example.com redirected you too many times

If I check the logs it shows me a bunch of lines like this:

> ```
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://example.com
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>       Request finished in 0.1026ms 307
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
>       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://example.com
> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
>       Request finished in 0.1837ms 307
> ```

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out the answer. This can be solved by adding the following code to ConfigureServices.cs:

```
services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ForwardLimit = 2;
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.10.1"));
    options.ForwardedForHeaderName = "X-Forwarded-For-My-Custom-Header-Name";
});
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-2.1#forwarded-headers-middleware-options